# Custom Static Links For Specific Menu Right Before/Next The wp_nav_menu Function now working

Tags: functions, menus, navigation

I am trying to add custom links next/before my built in menu, specifically for `main_menu`. I have placed this in my `functions.php` and have given list-items in `nav-menu-after.php` and also in the before file but it's not working.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items',do_wp_nav_menu_items );
function do_wp_nav_menu_items( $menu, $args = array() ) {
    if( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/nav-menu-before.php' ) && $args->theme_location == 'main_menu' ) {
        ob_start();
        @include TEMPLATEPATH . '/nav-menu-before.php';
        $nav_menu_before = ob_get_clean();
    }

    if( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/nav-menu-after.php'  ) && $args->theme_location == 'main_menu' ) {
        ob_start();
        @include TEMPLATEPATH . '/nav-menu-after.php';
        $nav_menu_after = ob_get_clean();
    }

    return $nav_menu_before . $menu . $nav_menu_after;
}
```

If I delete this part:

```
&& $args->theme_location == 'main_menu'
```

It works well but the custom static links appear in the whole menu I have (footer menu, primary menu). Not only `main_menu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will not pass that how many arguments you need in your callback function then [`add_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) will provide you only **one** and **first** argument.

Because default arguments for `add_filter` are

```
add_filter ( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 );
```

`$accepted_args` is **1** if you do not pass it.

Thus `$args` is always blank array in your callback function.

Change

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items',do_wp_nav_menu_items);
```

to

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'do_wp_nav_menu_items', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Great, Sumit! It now worked well.
Anyway I would like to ask, will I need to posted such these question based on the field I am asking?

I meant I have posted SAME question in stackoverflow but it got no single reply for 3-4 days, also several question based on wordpress. 

I can conclude then stackoverflow for common programming question, right? Like PHP or Java stuffs.

Again thanks @Sumit !

Comment: Yw :) Yes on Stackoverflow you can ask any programming language/CMS question. But if specific site exist then better to ask there like WordPress question on this site. But only core WordPress see [what you can ask here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The answer depends on quality of question and asker responsiveness. I can see you never closed a question on stackoverflow! You should always close question by [accepting answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if it solves your issue.